# npm run deploy failure when deploying React app to Github

Tags: reactjs, github, npm

**Problem:**
I am still very new to React and am trying to push my React app onto Github, but I keep running into an error when I deploy it on my console.

**Set Up:**
I am using Atom on a Windows 10 computer. I created my React app by using the commands, `npx create-react-app jordon`. I then followed the steps in [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8s4Ng-re0E). This is what my package.json looks like after following the tutorial:
[image]

I then went through the steps to initialize a github repository. However, after running `npm run deploy`, I come across an error:

[image]

I have tried to rerun the steps in the tutorial time after time, but either receive the same error, or an error that is resolved by uninstalling gh-pages from the folder but leads to the same error. At this point, I have not found any resources that would help me, since most people seem to have successfully ran the `npm run deploy` command. Any help would be much appreciated!